# Replace each RegExp match with different text in ActionScript 3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, replace

I'd like to know how to replace **each match** with a **different** text?
Let's say the source text is:

```
var strSource:String = "find it and replace what you find.";
```

..and we have a regex such as:

```
var re:RegExp = /\bfind\b/g;
```

Now, I need to replace each match with different text (for example):

```
var replacement:String = "replacement_" + increment.toString();
```

So the output would be something like:

```
output = "replacement_1 it and replace what you replacement_2";
```

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution finally..
Here it is, if anyone needs:

```
var re:RegExp = /(\b_)(.*?_ID\b)/gim;
var increment:int = 0;
var output:Object = re.exec(strSource);
while (output != null)
{
    var replacement:String = output[1] + "replacement_" + increment.toString();
    strSource = strSource.substring(0, output.index) + replacement + strSource.substring(re.lastIndex, strSource.length);
    output = re.exec(strSource);
    increment++;
}
```

Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a replacement function, something like this:

```
var increment : int = -1; // start at -1 so the first replacement will be 0
strSource.replace( /(\b_)(.*?_ID\b)/gim , function() {
    return arguments[1] + "replacement_" + (increment++).toString();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

leave off the g (global) flag and repeat the search with the appropriate replace string.  Loop until the search fails

Comment: Thanks but that won't work because in the actual code doesn't search for the word "find" (I gave this example to make the question clearer). It searches for something like .*? so; your way creates an endless loop..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about actionscript, but in many other regex implementations you can usually pass a callback function that will execute logic for each match and replace.